# Bootstrap navbar sidebar covering page text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar

Link to the navbar sidebar I am using: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

I'm having trouble figuring out how stop this sidebar from blocking text on a page. I've used navbars before and they appear to separate from the rest of the page, so pieces of the webpage don't disappear behind it. I understand this isn't an official bootstrap navbar, as I believe they don't fully support sidebars.

```css
// Place all the styles related to the Welcome controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/








/* BELOW HERE IS ALL NAVBAR CSS */
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #2e353d;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #23282e;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*    
    .collapsed{
       .arrow:before{
                 font-family: FontAwesome;
                 content: "\f053";
                 display: inline-block;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 float:right;
            }
     }
*/
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #181c20;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
  background-color: #4f5b69;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* ABOVE HERE IS ALL NAVBAR CSS */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Index</title>


</head>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">Navbar Sidebar</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
  
        <div class="menu-list">
  
            <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                  <a><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>
                    <%= link_to("Contact",
                      {:controller => 'welcome',
                         :action => 'contact'
                      }) %>                  
                  <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>
                
                
                <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Help <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>
                


                <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Lessons <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>  
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                  <li>Lesson 1</li>
                  <li>Lesson 2</li>
                  <li>Lesson 3</li>
                </ul>


                 <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile
                  </a>
                  </li>

                 <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users
                  </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </div>
</div>



<div class="main">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1>Navbar Sidebar</h1>
      <p> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <p> test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>

  </div>






</div> <!-- end main div -->



</div> <!-- close container fluid -->


</body>
</html>
```

Apparently imgur is currently having issues, and others (myself included) cannot upload images onto stack using imgur, so I have included a gyazo snapshot of the issue I am having:

https://gyazo.com/ad10f592a97335189c053d04411daff6

Comment: So you're saying you want it to "push" the content to the right instead of overlaying the content?

Comment: Yes. I don't want the navbar interfering with any content on pages. However, instead of having to move content over on every page, is there a way to just designate that area of the page to the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to change padding-left for both `.container` and `container-fluid` at all of the responsive breakpoints in CSS so that it looks good for your design. Note: these are the default bootstrap breakpoints, if you have custom ones, edit these to fit yours.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  .container, .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 100px; // just an example
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .container, .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 100px; // just an example
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .container, .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 100px; // just an example
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  .container, .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 100px; // just an example
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  .container, .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 100px; // just an example
  }
}
```

Comment: Applying this to .container and .container-fluid moved my sidebar to the right, as well as my text content. However, I applied these rules to my "main" div instead and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe making a div for all the content outside the navbar and giving that div some margin on the left so things on it are not covered by the nav bar would work.